# Is it possible to have html form submit multiple times?

Tags: html, forms, google-sites

I have a form that takes input from a dropdown list now and onsubmit opens a new tab getting the value from the selector.

Pseudoexample:

```
<form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" action="http://google." method="get" target="_blank">
  <select>
    <option value="com">com</option>
    <option value="co.uk">co.uk</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

My question is whether it would be possible to change the select to checkboxes and open n windows for n checkboxes checked. e.g. in this example if both com and co.uk are selected, 2 windows will open instead of google.com.co.uk

I know I can do it in javascript (and I have already) avoiding forms entirely. This is not an option however, as this is to be hosted on google sites, which don't allow `window.open()`

Comment: I guess what I have in mind is some form of a for-each loop through the inputs.. To the best of my knowledge there is no such thing though, so I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: make the form submit upon a value being checked off. if you use jquery it may be a bit easier.

Comment: if that were possible (haven't tried), wouldn't that open a new window and steal the focus? So to open a second one you'd have to go back to the original and click again, in essence opening windows 1 at a time, which is no different from what I have now. The idea is to open a group of windows at once

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript what are you trying to do? are you saying after the user selects all windows he wants open, he submits?

Comment: 1. user selects N checkboxes;
2. user hits submit;
3. user gets N windows opened, 1 for each checkbox. 

I repeat, window.open *is not available* in google sites.